# changing the default list colour of jquery mobile using css

Tags: css, jquery-ui

I have an html page given below

```
<body>
    <div data-role="page" id="home">

        <div data-role="header" data-position="fixed">
            <a href="#home" data-role="button" data-icon="home"></a>
        </div>
        <div data-role="content">
            <div class="content-primary">
                <form id="frm1">
                    <ul data-role="listview">
                        <li data-role="fieldcontain">
                            <label for="Name">name:</label>
                            <input type="text" Name="Name" id="Name" value="" />
                        </li>
                        <li data-role="fieldcontain">
                            <label for="No">no:</label>
                            <input type="text" No="No" id="No" value="" />
                        </li>
                        <li data-role="fieldcontain">
                            <label for="countryName">Country name:</label>
                            <input type="text" countryName="countryName" id="countryName" value="" />
                        </li>
                        <li data-role="fieldcontain">
                            <label for="stateName">State name:</label>
                            <input type="text" stateName="stateName" id="stateName" value="" />
                        </li>
                        <li data-role="fieldcontain">
                            <label for="cityName">City name:</label>
                            <input type="text" cityName="cityName" id="cityName" value="" />
                        </li>

                </form>
            </div>
        </div>
</body>
```

and i am using the following jquery 1.3.2 links displayed in the link given

http://jquerymobile.com/download/

and i have css file given below

```
.ui-body-c { background:#FFFFFF !important; }

.ui-page .ui-header {
    background:#0B0B3B !important;
}
.ui-page .ui-footer {
    background:#0B0B3B !important;
}
```

When i am using the above code the list which is displayed contains grey color.

how will i get white color instead grey to the list displayed.

Thanks in advance

Comment: Did any of the below solutions work for you?

Answer (score 1):

I can't actually test this but I have noticed oddities like this before when a css rule is defined as `background-color:` and you try to override with just `background:`

Try changing your rule to say `background-color:` instead. Also, if you can help it, stay clear of !important unless you're sure it's what you need. It can be a real pain when your css gets more complicated.

Answer (score 1):

All you need is to set `background-color` rule to `.ul-body`

```
.ui-body{
    background-color:#FFF;
}
```

Don't use `!improtant`, Keep it as a last resource.

*Note:* In case some other list might contain a class named `ui-body`, but you can give parent ID or class as selector to your custom class `.ui-body`

```
#Parent .ui-body{

}

.Parent .ui-body{

}
```

[**fiddle**](http://jsfiddle.net/CZAU8/)

Comment: Will this ui-body class not be added to a lot more items than just the list? This could be a troublesome override.

Comment: @Askanison4 Yeah may be, but user might take the parent element of the list that is containing a class named `.ui-body` so that will be `#parent/.parent .ui-body { }`